# How do I delete AsyncTasks when I'm done with them?

Tags: android, multithreading, memory, android-asynctask

So I have written a multi-threaded android app using AsyncTasks, I am having two problems:

1. When the task completes and returns the result the thread is still running in the background and I can't figure out how to make them go away,
2. When the home key is hit the worker threads continue to work and I'm not sure how to stop them. Anybody know how do do any of this?

So neither cancel or finish can stop these threads! What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to delete an AsyncTask, once onPostExecute is called it should be finished.

AsyncTask has a [cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) method that you can use to tell the task that you want it to stop itself. You can call that in [onPause()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29).

Comment: Exactly, once its done, let the OS take care of cleaning up if it needs to.

Comment: More specifically, AsyncTasks share a limited-size thread pool (creating / deleting threads isn't free, so letting the system reuse them where appropriate is good for performance). See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html for more on the Java thread pooling mechanism it uses behind the scenes, and I'd recommend reading the AOSP source for AsyncTask itself.

Comment: This is not working at all the thread continues to read as running in the debugger and I can see its impact on CPU usage so I know its not working right

Answer (score 0):

i use this activity base class for my activitys that performs AsynchronousTask, i stopped them on onStop methods i.e.

```
package com.xxxxxx.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class WkActivity extends Activity {

    protected AsynchronousTask aTask;
    private AlertDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        stopAsyncOperation();
    }

    private void stopAsyncOperation(){
        if( aTask != null){
            if( aTask.getStatus().equals( AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING )){
                aTask.cancel( true );
            }
        }
    }



}
```